# Android camera doesn't work after cordova compile

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, camera

I just compiled my cordova project to a .apk for android. You can open the (android) camera with a button.

When I was debugging my project the camera opened when you clicked on said button, but after compiling the project and installing it on my android smartphone, it wouldn't open the camera anymore.

Do you know how to make sure the camera opens, if you need more information, please let me know.

The camera opens with this code

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="capturePhotoWithData()">Capture Photo With Image Data</button>
```

**Javascript / JQuery**

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function capturePhotoWithData() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}
```

Comment: is your `onFail` callback firing?  If so, what is the error?  If not, are you seeing anything from logcat `adb logcat CordovaLog *:S`?

Comment: No, onFail is not firing. Where can I find `adb logcat Cordova` ? @laughingpine

Comment: logcat is a useful debugging tool for Android, it will spit out errors or exceptions as your application runs, so hopefully we will see why the camera fails to open.  If you have adb on your systems path variable, open up command prompt (if on windows) and run `adb logcat CordovaLog *:S` adb will connect to the device and start logcat.  If you don't have your path variable set, navigate to the android platform-tools folder and execute adb from there (or add the tools to your system path) More info: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Okay, I've got the debugging tool working. It says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined` .. Do you know how to fix that error? @laughingpine

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Perhaps there was an issue installing the plugin `cordova plugin list` will show you what is installed.  If you don't see something along the lines of `org.apache.cordova.camer` try installing again with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`  Otherwise, you might have to wrap the plugin call in a 'deviceready' event.

Comment: The camera plugin is in the `cordova list`.. So I'll try the device ready tomorrow.. Maybe we can start a discussion tomorrow? it's easier to talk in there. @laughingpine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75175/discussion-between-m-zeinstra-and-laughingpine).